# 70s (or earlier) movie with a monster dinosaur in England

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember from over 50 years ago (!) watching a film on UK television. I've always thought it was titled *The Beast From 20,000 Fathoms* but I've recently saw some of that and it's not the one I remember.

It could have been in colour but my parents only had a b+w TV back then.
Some circus people take a big Godzilla type dinosaur to England (maybe London?) and put it in a show.

Then there is panic because its super giant mother dinosaur comes to rescue it. There were jets and tanks hammering at this creature but  it didn't seem to harm it, they couldn't stop it destroying lots of buildings before it walked away with its young one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Gorgo* (1961)?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgo_(film)):

> Captain Joe Ryan is salvaging for treasure off the coast of Ireland, when a volcano erupts, nearly sinking his ship. Ryan and his first officer, Sam Slade, take the ship to Nara Island for repairs. As they enter harbour, they discover the floating carcasses of ancient marine animals, the first hint that something dangerous was awoken by the volcano eruption. [...]
>
> Ryan and his crew manage to capture the monster and haul it aboard their ship, tying it to the deck. **Soon, university scientists arrive on Nara, hoping to collect the monster for study, but Ryan has been offered a better deal by the owner of a circus in London.** When the ship arrives in London, the circus owner names it "Gorgo", after the iconic snake-haired woman, the Gorgon Medusa. It is exhibited to the public in Battersea Park.
>
> The scientists examine Gorgo and conclude that he is not yet an adult and that his mother must be at least 200 feet tall. **On that note of foreboding, we cut to Nara Island as Ogra, the mother of Gorgo, attacks. Ogra trashes the island, sinks a Royal Navy vessel and resists attack from other warships. Later, Ogra comes ashore in London**, still looking for her son, and goes on a rampage, despite being bombarded by tanks and infantry. Jets attack Ogra, but with no effect. **Having demolished much of London, Ogra rescues Gorgo and both mother and son return to the sea.**

---

Found with the Google query `science fiction movie creature circus mother`.

Comment: Done by MST3K in season 9.

Comment: "I'm waiting for Gorgo."

Comment: "Momma was an Ogra / Daddy was Godzilla / They named their baby Gorgo / It really was a thrilla!"

Answer (score 6):

The Beast from 20,000 Fathoms (1953), The Giant Behemoth (1959), and Gorgo (1961) were giant monster movie directed by Eugene Lourie.

All three are good giant monster movies, but the one that you remember seeing, with people bringing a Godzilla-like monster to be exhibited in London and its much larger mother coming for it, is Gorgo.